# How to print absolute time in TCL and relative time in TCL?

Tags: tcl

How to print absolute time in TCL?

The output would be something like `2018-03-07-14:32:09.040+05:30I-----`

I want to create a logic to print epoch microseconds. but I cannot use in build `clock milliseconds` to print the epoch microseconds.

Comment: Use `[clock microseconds]` to get the timestamp with microsecond precision (should be available since Tcl 8.5 IMO).

Comment: Still, I don't fully grasp the problem: the `14:32:09.040` portion of your example output indicates millisecond precision (`040` ms). So what are you really struggling with—time formatting or having a higher-resolution timestamp, or both? Please be precise, don't have us waste our time on guessing.

Answer (score 2):

You should refer to the [TCL documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/clock.htm#M8) for `clock microseconds`:

> Returns the current time as an integer number of microseconds.

However, `clock format` does not support this high resolution clock values. So you'll have to manually extract the microsecond decimal part of the result, use `clock format` to output the value with seconds precision and later manually add microseconds related decimal value (".XXXXXX") to it.

This scripts will output time with microseconds precision:

```
# get current time with microseconds precision:
set val [clock microseconds]
# extract time with seconds precision:
set seconds_precision [expr { $val / 1000000 }]
# find number of microseconds:
set microseconds [expr { $val - $seconds_precision*1000000 }]

# output the epoc with microseconds precision:
puts [format "%s.%06d" [clock format $seconds_precision -format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"] $microseconds]
```

Outputs `2018-03-07 11:04:59.946580`

You can adapt the script if you prefer milliseconds precision or if you want to show time zone.

Comment: @DonalFellows: True, updated my post and will try to work on an example.

Comment: You needed to be using `format` to add that value in so as to add leading zeroes when required.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you :

```html
set milliseconds [clock clicks]
variable time [format "%s_%03d" [clock format [clock seconds] -format %Y%m%d_%H%M%S] [expr {$milliseconds % 1000}] ]

puts $time
```